# Self referencing nested objects

Tags: javascript, object

Dear JavaScript masters.

I understand to dozens of articles about scopes, objects, this keyword etc.
But these shows only basic examples.
Most of code I saw is long and messy JavaScripts.

I would like to achieve behavior, where 'this' in each object is referencing to object itself.
This test snippet has the required behavior.

QUESTION:
  Is there a better way to achieve this ?
  Is't it anti-pattern ?

```js
var mainObject = {};
mainObject.childObject = {};

/* CHILD OBJECT
 */
(function() {

        function childObject(){
                this.property = 'childObject';
                this.childMethod = function(){
                        console.log( 'child obj method' );
                };
        }
        return childObject;

})().apply(mainObject.childObject);


/* MAIN OBJECT
 */
(function() {

        function mainObject(){
                this.property = 'mainObject';
                console.log( 'main obj method' );
                this.childObject.childMethod();
        }
        return mainObject;

})().apply(mainObject);



console.log( mainObject );
console.log( mainObject.childObject );
```

Comment: Yes. You only need an IIFE to enclose sth. but you dont enclose anything.

Comment: You might want to go back to the basic examples. You'd learn that "*'this' in each object is referencing …*" makes no sense - the `this` keyword is scoped to functions, not to objects.

Comment: Also it's really confusing that you use the names `mainObject` and `childObject` both for objects and functions. It's not even clear what the "required behaviour" of your script is - does it do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it qualifies as an "anti-pattern" per se, but there are certainly a lot of unnecessary things going on. Here's a simplified example, maintaining the static functions you declared:

```js
var mainObject = {};
mainObject.childObject = {};

function modifyChild() {
  this.property = 'childObject';
  this.childMethod = function() {
    console.log('child obj method');
  };
}

modifyChild.call(mainObject.childObject);

function modifyMain() {
  this.property = 'mainObject';
  console.log('main obj method');
  this.childObject.childMethod();
}

modifyMain.call(mainObject);

console.log(mainObject);
console.log(mainObject.childObject);
```

In general, if you want a static function you can call directly, without chaining `.call()` or `.apply()`, and pass in a `this` context, you can `.call.bind()` it to itself:

```js
var someFunction = (function () {
  function someFunction () {
    console.log(this);
  }
  
  return someFunction.call.bind(someFunction);
})()

someFunction({ foo: 'bar' });
```

Comment: @JonasW. is it really? I'd love to hear an explanation for why that's so bad, I've never heard that accusation before.

Comment: Or at least i would never use it. I dont see any advantage of `this` over `someFunction`

Comment: @JonasW. I personally don't see any advantage myself, but I figured it'd be helpful information if that's what OP really wanted to do for some reason.